# Why useLocalStorage put " around string?

Tags: reactjs

Storing user is like this:

```js
const [fbUserId, setFbUserId] = useLocalStorage<string | undefined>(
    'fbUserId_v3',
    undefined
)
```

and `useLocalStorage` stores it like this: `"10219985418219945"` Why the extra `"` is needed? Why not the raw string is stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's serialised as JSON, so that you could store not only strings, but other types too, like numbers, objects, booleans, etc.

References:

- https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5f34b051dfb708ef6e8dc8e55d5e1bbd209381e8/packages/react-devtools-shared/src/devtools/views/hooks.js#L173